# How do you use a .bat file (or any kind of file) to run an exe or msi program without admin rights

Tags: batch-file, non-admin

So I've only done one thing with a bat file, and that was install steam with this command that I got off of a YouTube video: set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker start steamsetup. Now I want to use a bat file or something like that to download valorant and the epic games launcher without admin rights. The epic games launcher download is an msi file (idk if anyone elses is an msi but mine is for some reason) and valorant is an exe file. It would be nice to know scripts to generally download exe, msi, and other kinds of files without the admin password as well, so if anyone knows how, I would much appreciate an answer, but at this point in time, I'm trying to download the epic games launcher and valorant. Thanks!

Comment: Downloading is merely the first hurdle… without admin you'll never install them.

Comment: @Tetsujin if no admin rights are necessary, you can either start the msi or use msiexec to install it. Only if admin rights are necessary, then you will indeed run into problems.

Comment: Also, powershell can download files from the internet and save them locally. I don't think this is going to work in plain .batch scripting, unless you invoke powershell or another scripting as well.

Comment: if you use Windows 10 you can use curl do download:
curl -O www.somesite.com/downloadlink.exe

Comment: i already downloaded steam with a regular bat file, but i just cant find the name for the epic games launcher. every i try to do the batch file for the epic games launcher, it says it cant find the name i put in. it would be nice to know how to find the name of programs to use for batch files